Write text on bitmap, HBITMAP "not compatible" with HDC
I am trying to use the code mentioned Write text on BITMAPINFO in memory. My code is below.
BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo = {0}; //debug
MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader); //debug
int lines; //debug

HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateBitmap(10, 10, 1, 8, bmp_buffer);
GetDIBits(memdc, hbitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS); //debug
HBITMAP oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
TextOut(memdc, 0, 0, "123", 3);
SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
lines = GetDIBits(memdc, hbitmap, 0, 10, bmp_buffer, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS); //<-here was used other BMInfo structure
DeleteObject(hbitmap);
DeleteDC(memdc);
ReleaseDC(0, hdc);

It does not work as expected. During troubleshooting I had discovered the GetDIBits returns 0 lines, like could not copy the content of bitmap to bmp_buffer, later I tried to observe current selected bitmap within memdc by executing GetCurrentObject(memdc, OBJ_BITMAP) and it does not change, so for some reason hbitmap is not "selected" within memdc.
Then I had tried many different ideas and I found if hbitmap is created by CreateCompatibleBitmap(), lines of bmp_buffer are updated. I queried the attributes of such created bitmap and it looks it has correct dimensions but 1 bit color setting. Following this track, if I change to hbitmat=CreateBitmap(10, 10, 1, 1, bmp_buffer) it kind works, at least lines != 0, and some bytes in bmp_buffer are updated. This suggests  hbitmap created by CreateBitmap(10, 10, 1, 8, bmp_buffer) is "not compatible" with memdc. Changing to monochromatic is not solution, as I need colors in my bitmap.
GDI documentation says any DC created by CreateCompatibleDC() is monochromatic and 1x1 pixel size. It also says it must be update later to use color images different sizes, but there is no suggestion how to change color size. What am I doing wrong, the code I follows just use 24 bit per pixel and it worked in some other application.

For GetDIBits to work you need to properly populate several of the fields in your MyBMInfo.bmiHeader structure beyond the size.

@500-InternalServerError can you share hint what to look for? I suspect the problem in my code is little earlier than GetDIBits, closer to the moment when internal bitmap is created.

Did you use CreateCompatibleBitmap with the original DC ? You shouldn't use it with the memory DC.

@ElderBug What could be "original DC" if I want to have virtual canvas to do TextOut and then save it to file?
I tried to use result of CreateDC(0) or CreateDC(hwnd to main window) and I hit the same wall, but this time GetDIBits works only for 32bit color space.

The problem with Device-Dependent Bitmaps (DDB), is that they are device-dependent, so the format is the format of the DC. Since it is 32bpp in your case, you are stuck with 32bpp afaik. If you don't want that, you should go with DIB instead of DDB.

@ElderBug It sounds like use incorrect API, what is the correct way to create DC to work later TextOut and generate bitmap to file?

What's your goal exactly? If you never intend to use a device output, then GDI isn't the right tool for that. Drawing text without a device makes no sense in GDI. What should the text look like for you? For GDI it entirely depends on the device. Depending on the monitor, ClearType will render differently. GDI is also meant for printer, where the rendering is again very different. You can't just say "draw me some text" with no context. So to make it simple, you either use GDI with a DC that works for you (screen for example), or you use another library like DirectWrite or freetype.

@ElderBug My goal is to render bitmap file using windows fonts. I expect memory device context has such functionality. Regarding to my problem with color coding, microsoft documentation says https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/memory-device-contexts "Before an application can begin drawing, it must select a bitmap with the appropriate width and height into the DC by calling the SelectObject function."
Similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181728/create-memory-device-context-for-a-bitmap-not-a-device-not-display but calling CreateCompatibleDC(0) not work for me.

@ElderBug after consideration, my problem is not the bitmap I am working with TextOut is device/screen or whatever compatible. But at the end I would like to save this image after adding plots and images from application to 8bit BMP file.

Honestly you could just work with your compatible DC at 32bpp, I don't think there would be any problem. You probably should try to disable cleartype but I'm not sure how to do that.

@ElderBug But then how to map 32bpp bitmap to 8bpp data? Will 'GetDIBits' will do that automatic?

GetDIBits should convert if I'm not mistaken. You have to change the bitmap info struct to your desired one.

@ElderBug It is kind working, it took me few hours to discover that 'BITMAPINFO' used as argument needs to have a palette, without that GetDiBits refuse to work. However it still does not work fully as expected. If I make TextOut("123") and I dump image in 32bpp mode, I get sequences FF-FF-FF-00 and 00-00-00-00, this is expected, white and black colors. But if I create palelete containing 2 colors 'bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 2', the first color FF-FF-FF-00 and the second one 00-00-00-00 and tries to map image to 8bpp I get two kind of bytes in output 0x00 and 0x13. Any advice?

The size of the table is in biClrUsed, not biClrImportant.

Also, it seems you try to input a color table, but I think the color table is an output. If you supply 8bpp as format, GetDIBits will fill 256 entries in the table.

@ElderBug  I tried setting both 'biClrUsed' and 'biClrImportant'. It seems I may have all pieces of this puzzle, but still trying to learn something, I still do not know where those values come from, trying to call GetDIBColorTable on memdc does not bring any value, as memdc is RGB, so function just fails. Two new findings calling GetDIBits(... DIB_RGB_COLORS) gets pixel data starting from FF FF 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF, but GetDIBits(... DIB_PAL_COLORS) gets 13 13 00 00 00 00 13 13 13 13 00 00 ... So there is a kind of palette maping used internally by GetDIBits

@ElderBug I read the documentation again GetDiBtis actually generate new pallete and WRITES into BITMAPINFO, not using provided palette. For DIB_RGB_COLORS palette is four bytes, RGB plus one byte, for DIB_PAL_COLORS palette is set of 16 bit numbers (exact as doc says), but under position 0x13 there is value 0x13. There is 20 color windows palette, where black color is at the end of list (0x13 = 19 dec) BUT this palette is constructed as first 10 and last 10 (numbers 245-255) are defined. But if GetDiBtis tries to group "know" color at start it could explain my observations.

Yes as I said the table is an output. You also have to set bbiCompression to BI_RGB for paletted.

I had few misunderstanding while reading documentation and example code used in questions, they are summarized below:

GetDIBits does not use provided pallete, just itself overwrite existing memory array. It is explicly stated in documentation, I missed that part. Also does not obey biClrUsed neither biClrImportant, so allocate enought memory.
Is is not possible to create context with specified amount bits per pixel, that compatible bitmap will inherit. GetDC(0) return context from desktop which is 32 bits per pixel and HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc) creates context with 1bpp (as it is in documentation).
It is better not to write directly on bmp file image buffer by GetDIBits() but to use intermediate buffer and copy the image to bmp file image buffer. It gives possibilities to control position and color of printed text.

My working example:
char* local_img = malloc(100*100);
BITMAPINFO local_bmi = malloc(sizeof(BITMAPINFO)+sizeof(COLORREF)*255);
local_bmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
local_bmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
local_bmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8;
local_bmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = 100;
local_bmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = 100;
local_bmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = 0;
local_bmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 100*100;
local_bmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 256;
local_bmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 256;

HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 100, 100);
HBITMAP oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
TextOut(memdc, 0, 0, "123", 3);
SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
GetDIBits(memdc, hbitmap, 0, 100, local_img, local_bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
DeleteObject(hbitmap);
DeleteDC(memdc);
ReleaseDC(0, hdc);  
free(local_bmi);

//use local_img for own purpose, then free it!!!

